# Use variables from tidy select within paste()

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Assume the following function

```
library(tidyverse)
nest_fun <- function(data, groups) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(pick({{groups}})) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(filename = paste({{groups}}[1], {{groups}}[2], "file.png", sep = "_"))
}
nest_fun(data = mtcars, groups = c(vs, am))
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
# # Groups:   vs, am [4]
#      vs    am data              filename    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <list>            <chr>       
# 1     0     1 <tibble [6 × 9]>  0_1_file.png
# 2     1     1 <tibble [7 × 9]>  1_1_file.png
# 3     1     0 <tibble [7 × 9]>  1_0_file.png
# 4     0     0 <tibble [12 × 9]> 0_0_file.png
```

The function works fine as long as I group by exactly 2 variables. How could I write the function such that I can group by an arbitrary number of variables and still get filename correct?

Comment: `... mutate(filename = paste0(paste({{groups}}, collapse="_"), "_file.png"))`.

Comment: @Limey, post as an answer ... it's simpler than my (since-deleted), much clearer and fewer changes. (Though I stand by my recommend of adding an argument for `data=` defaulting to `mtcars` :-).

Comment: @Limey Thanks, I will accept if you post as an answer.

Comment: @r2evans: it's not often I'm both quicker and better than you!  This is one for the scrapbook... ;=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `collapse` argument of `paste` (and `paste0`) pastes down the elements of a vector, whereas `sep` pastes across the arguments of the call.  Therefore you can get what you want with nested calls to `paste`/`paste0`.

I strongly support @r2evans' comment about providing the data frame as an argument to your function.  It is simply good practice  (and allows you to pipe your function if you wish).  I see you've already actioned that in the question.  However, using `data` - which is the name of a built-in function - as its name is not ideal.

So...

```
library(tidyverse)

nest_fun <- function(d=mtcars, groups = c(vs, am)) {
  d %>% 
    group_by(pick({{groups}})) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(filename = paste0(paste({{groups}}, collapse="_"), "_file.png"))
}

nest_fun()

# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   vs, am [4]
     vs    am data              filename    
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>            <chr>       
1     0     1 <tibble [6 × 9]>  0_1_file.png
2     1     1 <tibble [7 × 9]>  1_1_file.png
3     1     0 <tibble [7 × 9]>  1_0_file.png
4     0     0 <tibble [12 × 9]> 0_0_file.png

mtcars %>% nest_fun(c(vs, am, gear))

# A tibble: 7 × 5
# Groups:   vs, am, gear [7]
     vs    am  gear data              filename      
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>            <chr>         
1     0     1     4 <tibble [2 × 8]>  0_1_4_file.png
2     1     1     4 <tibble [6 × 8]>  1_1_4_file.png
3     1     0     3 <tibble [3 × 8]>  1_0_3_file.png
4     0     0     3 <tibble [12 × 8]> 0_0_3_file.png
5     1     0     4 <tibble [4 × 8]>  1_0_4_file.png
6     0     1     5 <tibble [4 × 8]>  0_1_5_file.png
7     1     1     5 <tibble [1 × 8]>  1_1_5_file.png
nest_fun()
```